# Define a variable in group and use in test declarations

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm writing tests for my rails app and I've found out that as almost an the tests are run on the set of some **n** variables, I can write them as follows:

```
[var1, var2, …].each do   
    describe … do
     .
     .
    end

    it … do
     .
     .
    end
end
```

and so on. But I can't find a way how to put all that array into a variable, so I can just use `variables.each do …`.

I've tried before(:each), before(:all) and just a declaration of and instance variable *(one that starts with @-sign)* in a `describe` group, but all my tries were useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `variables` in the `Rspec.configure` block:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.add_setting :variables, :default =>  [1, 2]
end
```

And use it inside your specs like this:

```
RSpec.configuration.variables.each do |i|
end
```

You can also declare `variables` outside of the RSpec configuration block like in the example below, but since you *probably* already have this block, better keep things clean.

```
RSpec.configuration.add_setting :variables, :default =>  [1, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it's not the best variable naming _(`@variables` looks way better than `RSpec.configuration.variables`)_ but it helps me to DRY my tests. Thank you!